# How do I plot lines in the future in pine script?

Tags: pine-script, trading

I have been trying to plot take profit and stop loss lines for a script I wrote, but I am struggling with plotting lines in the future.

I have tried using the plot and line.new functions but with no success.

[An example of what I would like to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Me0iR.png)

Comment: Search the Public Library for examples; you will find plenty: https://www.tradingview.com/scripts/supportandresistance/

Comment: Hi, what exactly did you try and why was it not a success?

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the values you want to plot on the graph then set offset. Something like this,

```
plot(close, offset = 1, color = color.black, linewidth=2)
```

here offset will be number bars in the future. i.e 1 is calculated bar in future.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote something that does exactly what you seek. I plot the Daily Pivot lines to the right of the bars, so they don't get in the way. The trick is to use a trendline instead of a "plot" line, and have the trendline offset by a certain amount of time rather than using the "offset" feature.

You can see I calculate the time value of one bar using labeldt, then define the x1 and x2 options using (time + (labeldt * 20)), which means to begin the trendline at the current bar and plot it 20 bars into the future. The y1 and y2 options define what price level it will be plotted on.

Good luck

```
/////////////////////
// F L O O R   P I V O T S
// 
/////////////////////

labeldt = time - time[1]

/////////////////
//LINE PRICE CALCULATIONS
/////////////////////////
PPFunc() =>
    xHighPP = high[1]
    xLowPP = low[1]
    xClosePP = close[1]
    [xHighPP, xLowPP, xClosePP]

[xHigh, xLow, xClose] = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', PPFunc())

//xHigh  = security(tickerid,1440, high[1])
//xLow   = security(tickerid,1440, low[1])
//xClose = security(tickerid,1440, close[1])

vPP = (xHigh+xLow+xClose) / 3

/////////////////////////

//LINE PLOT

PlothlineDayPivotPoint = line.new(x1=time, y1=vPP, x2=time + (labeldt * 20), y2=vPP, extend=extend.none, color= #0000ff, xloc=xloc.bar_time)

//LINE STYLE

line.set_width(PlothlineDayPivotPoint, 1)

//LINE DELETER

line.delete(PlothlineDayPivotPoint[1])

/////////////////////
```

For your purposes you can ignore the "Line Price Calculations" section - that is just me calculating the price level.